# Python - Get values from dicts when key is a label

Tags: python, dictionary

im trying to access to some values where the keys are a special variable (label).

The main_dict is the following and was generated by jsondiff.diff module:

```
{18: {'value': '5002'}, 26: {'value': 'http://config-service:8080/'}, insert: [(19, {'name': 'alfalfa', 'value': 'alfalfa1'})], delete: [27]}
```

Where "label" and "delete" has this special attributes.

When i try to show the keys from the dict the output is :

```
main_dict[k].keys()
dict_keys([18, 26, insert, delete])
```

But when i try get the values of this keys, python output report the following errors:

```
main_dict[k]['insert']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'insert'

main_dict[k]['delete']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'delete'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Apparently the key is not a string. Could you provide the type of the key? k = main_dict[k].keys and then type(k[3])

Comment: Hi @haxor789,
keys = list(main_dict[k].keys())

keys
[18, 26, insert, delete]

type(keys[2])
<class 'jsondiff.symbols.Symbol'>

Comment: Well then you'd need one of those as the key rather than the string. So idk import jsondiff.symbols.Symbol  and then Symbol("delete") for example

Comment: v has the variable inside the foor loop.
main_dict[k][Symbol(v)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: <unprintable KeyError object>

I saw in the docs from this module that this symbols has a __str__ return, so i create a new_dict forcing a str for this keys and now i can get the values, it´s a little bit "dirty" but works

new_dict = {}
for v in main_dict[k].items():
    i,val = v
    new_dict[str(i)] = val

print(new_dict["$insert"])
[(19, {'name': 'alfalfa', 'value': 'alfalfa1'})]